# How do I use AIDL tool from command line using SDK sample code?

Tags: android, aidl

My question concerns using aidl.exe (on a Windows system) from the command line.  This question has nothing to do with Eclipse, Netbeans, etc.

Included with the Android SDK are the following three AIDL definition files:

IRemoteService.aidl
   IRemoteServiceCallback.aidl
   ISecondary.aidl

located in the following directory:

C:\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-2.1\samples\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\app

For the sake of simplicity, I copied aidl.exe into the above directory.  Then, from a console Window, I successfully used the following two commands to generate .java files:

C:\Android-project\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\app>aidl IRemoteServiceCallback.aidl
   C:\Android-project\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\app>aidl ISecondary.aidl

Invoking these commands produced the files IRemoteServiceCallback.java and ISecondary.java, respectively.  So far so good.

I note that both .aidl files are simple; they include no 'import' statements.

The remaining .aidl file, IRemoteService.aidl, does include the following import statement on line 19:

import com.example.android.apis.app.IRemoteServiceCallback;

The problem arises when I run the AIDL tool on this file:

```
  C:\Android-project\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\app>aidl IRemoteService.aidl
```

Doing so causes the following error message to be printed in the console window:

IRemoteService.aidl:19: couldn't find import for class com.example.android.apis.app.IRemoteServiceCallback

The AIDL tool evidently could not locate the IRemoteServiceCallback.aidl file in the same directory in which it was running.  According to the AIDL tool's "usage" message, there is a command that apparently can be used to resolve this problem:

```
  -I<DIR>    search path for import statements.
```

The problem: I have not been able to specify -I in such a way as to avoid the error message and have the AIDL tool generate a .java file from the .aidl file with an 'import' statement.  (Note: I set the Windows environment variable 'path' to my current directory.)  Here are a few variations I've tried:

```
-Ic:\com\example\android\apis\app
-Ic:/com/example/android/apis/app
-I.\
-I.
```

I must be missing something simple.  Surprisingly, even though I've seen variations of this question posted in various places, I have yet to see an answer or any documentation about AIDL command line usage (other than the aidl.exe USAGE info).  Can someone clue me in?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must provide the folder path to the source files, but WITHOUT the path after the base src folder. 
So, in your case the right command is:

```
C:\Android-project\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\app>aidl -IC:\Android-project\ApiDemos\src\ IRemoteService.aidl
```

Comment: I think this is the only place on the internet this is documented.  Thank you, you are a hero.

Comment: Indeed, despite lots of troubleshooting and Googling I was not able to figure this out before finding this post.  Also, note that on Windows, aidl.exe will crash (producing a .dmp CrashDump) if using network share UNC (e.g. `\\host\workspace`) instead of mapped drive (e.g. `H:\workspace`).

Answer (score 5):

It taked 3 hours useless search on google and 1,5 hours search on yandex. The solution is here:

http://programmingissues.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/cant-use-aidl-file-in-eclipse-android-project/

You need to add -p/path/to/framework.aidl key

Comment: You made my day! BTW, aidl's own description of the -p flag is idiotic.

Comment: Also, on Windows, aidl.exe will crash (producing a .dmp CrashDump) if using network share UNC (e.g. `\\host\workspace`) instead of mapped drive (e.g. `H:\workspace`).

Answer (score 4):

As you mention, there isn't much documentation.

So if you enable verbose build output in Eclipse (under Window > Preferences > Android > Build, I think), you can see in the Console what commands, including `aidl` and `aapt`, are executed when the Eclipse plugin does a build.

Alternatively, if you can understand C you could check out the aidl source code in the AOSP.

Comment: Mmmmm, verbose builds -- much better.  Thanks, Christopher

Comment: Thank you Sir. `Window > Preferences > Android > Build (Build output: Verbose)`, then `Window > Show View > Console`, then in the Console tab, click the 'Display Selected Console` icon, to switch from DDMS to Android --- finally gave me the aidl.exe (and more) verbose debug log I desperately need.